# ¿Iniciar mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Acabo de instalar mongodb en mi pc, la cual tiene sistema operativo linux con la distribución antergos.

Al parecer no funciona el comando : sudo service mongod start
Probé también sólo con: service mongod start y sigue sin funcionar

¿Alguien sabe donde puede estar el problema?

Al hacer un mongo --version obtengo los siguientes datos:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
git version: 876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Comment: ¿Ves algún error en consola cuando intentas iniciar el servicio?

Comment: Me aparece el siguiente mensaje tras hacer cualquiera de los comandos anteriores: service: command not found

Comment: @PedroFumero debes ser root para manipular servicios.

Comment: Si, he utilizado también el super usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que no eres root, así que primero escribe en la consola:

```
su
```

Enter, luego deberás escribir la contraseña de superusuario/root.
Ahora sí, puedes continuar.

### Para instalar mongodb como servicio:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-server
```

### Para iniciar el servicio de MongoDB

```
#Debes ser root
service mongodb start
```

### Para configurar mongodb

```
nano /etc/mongodb.conf
```

### Reiniciar el servicio mongodb

```
#Debes ser root
service mongodb restart

#Tambíen podrías:
service mongodb stop
service mongodb start
```

Comment: Dado que la distribución linux que utilizo es Antergos, y es basada en arch, no me es posible utilizar apt, sin embargo he podido llegar a la solución. La misma ha sido la siguiente:

Busque el nombre del servicio con: systemctl list-unit-files | grep mongo y obtuve: systemctl list-unit-files | grep mongo

Luego simplemente escribo en la consola: sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service y por último: sudo systemctl start mongodb.service